# Riemann Integral Property for Continuous, Monotonic, Non-negative Function

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, proof-verification, continuity, riemann-sum

If $f$ is continuous, non-negative, and monotonically increasing function on $[0,∞)$, then prove that $\int^{x}_{0} f(t)dt\leq xf(x)$  $\forall x ≥ 0$

My attempt:

Define $F(x)=\int^{x}_{0} f(t)dt$. Since $f$ is continuous, then $F$ is differentiable in $[0,∞)$.

Choose $x\in [0,∞)$

By Mean Value Theorem, $F^{'}(x_{0})=[F(x)-F(0)]/x$ for some $x_{0}\in [0,x]$

$\implies x.F^{'}(x_{0})=[F(x)-F(0)]$. Since $F(0)=0$, we have $x.F^{'}(x_{0})=F(x)$. Also, $F^{'}(x_{0})=f(x_{0})$. So, $x.f(x_{0})=\int^{x}_{0} f(t)dt $.

Since $f(x_{0})\geq 0, x\geq 0$ and $f$ is monotonically increasing, then $\forall x>x_{0}$,

$x.f(x)\geq \int^{x}_{0} f(t)dt$.

Since $x$ is arbitrary, we can choose $x$ arbitrarily close to $0$ and hence the corresponding $x_{0}$ can be found arbitrarily close to $0$. So, for all $x$, we have $x.f(x)\geq \int^{x}_{0} f(t)dt$

Is the proof correct and rigorous enough? If not, then please suggest an alternative proof in full.

Comment: You should have chosen $x\in (0,\infty)$

Comment: Why can I not choose $[0,∞)$? Please explain

Comment: you're dividing by $x$ in the next step

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I totally missed that

Comment: So, how should I account for the case of $x$ separately?

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal the Mean Value Theorem does also only apply on intervals, and $[0,0]$ is not an interval under the sense that the theorem requires it

Comment: So, is there a loophole in the proof. This is my first analysis. Please suggest me if anything is wrong.

Comment: @Martin except for the $x=0$ case, it's correct.

Comment: ok thanks guys.

Comment: There's a much simpler proof: fix $x$ and let $g(t)=f(x)$ for $t\in[0,x]$.  Then $  f(t)\le g(t)$ for all $t\in[0,x]$. Thus $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt\le\int_0^x g(t)\, dt=xf(x)$.

Comment: $f$ is increasing; so, for $t\in[0,x]$, $f(t)\le f(x)=g(t)$.

Comment: $g$ is a constant function. Evaluate the integral.

Comment: Oh right, we fixed $x$.

Comment: Even more simply, just note for fixed $x$, $ f(x)\cdot x$ is an upper Riemann sum for $f$ on $[0,x]$.

Comment: Absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, except with the following minor points:

- Handle the case where $x=0$ separately as Neeraj said, because you want to avoid dividing by 0.

  - You can instead use directly the version of mean value theorem $\exists c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $(b-a)f'(c)=f(b)-f(a)$.
  - However, the "stronger" mean value theorem says when $a<b$, $\exists c \in (a,b)$ s.t. $(b-a)f'(c)=f(b)-f(a)$.
- You should immediately define $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt$, and not say that $F$ is the indefinite integral earlier.
- Edit: I didn't see the last line earlier. I think it was meant to handle the case $x=0$, but it is not complete unless you say that both sides are continuous functions. As I said in my comments, why don't you just do $x=0$ separately?

Also, there is a simple proof.

$\int_0^x f(t) dt\le\int_0^x f(x) dt=xf(x)$.

(since $\forall t\in [0,x], f(t)\le f(x)$)

Comment: You missed the variable of integartion

Comment: This is what I have defined, right?

Comment: About my definition of $F(x)$, I have written the same thing as you have done, is it something else that you want to suggest?

Comment: @Martin he means that you first define $F$ as the indefinite integral $\int f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ and then you define it later as $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt$

Comment: oh ok, I will correct that now in the post. However, as suggested "directly use the version of mean value theorem $∃c∈[a,b] s.t. (b−a)f′(c)=f(b)−f(a)$, this will also include $0$, won't it?

Comment: Yes, that would. However, the 0 case is exceedingly simple. Both sides evaluate to 0..!